# Convert the map RDD into dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.6.0, I have input map RDD (key,value) pair and want to convert to dataframe.

Input format RDD:

```
((1, A, ABC), List(pz,A1))
((2, B, PQR), List(az,B1))
((3, C, MNR), List(cs,c1))
```

Output format:

```
+----+----+-----+----+----+
| c1 | c2 | c3  | c4 | c5 |
+----+----+-----+----+----+
| 1  | A  | ABC | pz | A1 |
+----+----+-----+----+----+
| 2  | B  | PQR | az | B1 |
+----+----+-----+----+----+
| 3  | C  | MNR | cs | C1 |
+----+----+-----+----+----+
```

Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with `datasets` as `datasets` are *optimized* and *typesafe* `dataframes`.

first you need to create a `case class` as

```
case class table(c1: Int, c2: String, c3: String, c4:String, c5:String)
```

then you would just need a `map` function to parse your data to the `case class` and call `.toDS`

```
rdd.map(x => table(x._1._1, x._1._2, x._1._3, x._2(0), x._2(1))).toDS().show()
```

you should have following output

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4| c5|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  A|ABC| pz| A1|
|  2|  B|PQR| az| B1|
|  3|  C|MNR| cs| c1|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

you can use `dataframe` as well, for that you can use `.toDF()` instead of `.toDS()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  val a = Seq(((1,"A","ABC"),List("pz","A1")),((2, "B", "PQR"), 
          List("az","B1")),((3,"C", "MNR"), List("cs","c1")))
  val a1 = sc.parallelize(a);
  val a2 = a1.map(rec=>
           (rec._1._1,rec._1._2,rec._1._3,rec._2(0),rec._2(1))).toDF()
   a2.show()
    +---+---+---+---+---+
    | _1| _2| _3| _4| _5|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
    |  1|  A|ABC| pz| A1|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
    | 2 | B |PQR| az| B1|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
    | 3 | C |MNR| cs| C1|
```